# Amazon EC2 and Cyberduck PEM file

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp, cyberduck

I've set up an EC2 instance and can get in via ssh through terminal (I'm on a Mac).

I want to be able to get in via cyberduck and sftp, and can with the ec2-user@mydomain.com login but then I don't have sufficient privileges to actually do anything.

When I try to login via cyberduck with root@mydomain.com it won't let me, says

> Illegal sftp packet len: 1349281121.

I created a new user but don't know how to get a `.pem` file uploaded for them.

Comment: Check this out if you use FileZilla http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only login over SFTP as the `ec2-user` user, so you'll need to SSH into the machine first, change the permissions, then you can upload files.

Alternatively, you can use `scp` on the command line.

Comment: Sorry for the need for clarification, but what should I change the permissions to?

Comment: is there any danger in changing them to 777 for the entire folder? It worked, but I don't want to open a huge security vulnerability just because it worked...

Comment: You can switch to `0777` while uploading, then change it back when you're done. You generally want the directory itself to be `0755` and the files inside to be `0644`.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off giving access to the user or group for the file they need to access than to allow root login via SSH.

You can do this with `chmod` and `chown` tools via terminal.